# ArcPy/Python method to ascertain VBA requirements in mxd

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, mxd, vba

I need to be able to look at an MXD and ascertain if it has any VBA code embedded within it.  It's ArcGIS 10.2, and the VBA extension tool is installed on all machines on the estate, but not all mxd files will have VBA code embedded in them.  I've been looking all over but cannot find a method in ArcPy to check the mxds

Comment: so you need to check if a certain extension is enabled on the mxd? HERE is the arcpy function to check out extensions, do a try, if then statement to see if its already checked out if not then check out  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkoutextension.htm

Comment: No, the extension will always be enabled on all of the machines, but some of the mxd's themselves will have embedded vba code, some will not. I need to find out which ones have embedded code an which ones don't.

Thanks for the link though, as it will come in handy walking down the line.

Comment: I assume you are making the distinction between VBA in an MXD  (and that MXD can be anywhere on your network) and VBA in the normal template which will be in the users profile on each machine?

Comment: Indeed @Hornbydd - I am literally only interested if any mxd's have embedded VBA in them.

Comment: I think MXD Doctor (which I havent used in quite some time) will report on VBA:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000300000019000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using oletools library and checking for the length of vba code in the document.  It has boilerplate code for the Normal.mxt which you can handle.

Effectively:

```
from oletools.olevba3 import VBA_Parser, VBA_Scanner
vba = VBA_Parser(file)
if vba.detect_vba_macros(): 
    filename, stream_path, vba_filename, vba_code = map(str,(vba.extract_macros())) 
    results = vba_scanner.scan(include_decoded_strings=True)
        for kw_type, keyword, description in results:
            #print or disseminate what you need
```

So I managed to elicit the code length, and also code file paths, like classes and modules.  I believe the lebngth of boilerplate code in there is arund 305 chars.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe arcpy exposes such properties. You need to be able to drill down into the VBProject and then VBComponents to check if a code module exists. It's been many years since I have mooched around at that level of the object model. Below is some incomplete .NET VB code but I never quite got it working... Hopefully gives you an idea or someone reading this who is more up to scratch with it where I was going. It tests a single MXD but you could easily expand this into a loop.

```vb
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim pApp As IApplication
        Try
            ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop)
            Dim pAO As IAoInitialize
            pAO = New AoInitialize
            pAO.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic)

            Dim pmxDoc As IMxDocument
            pmxDoc = New MxDocument
            Dim pdoc As IDocument
            pdoc = pmxDoc
            pApp = pdoc.Parent
            pApp.OpenDocument("C:\Scratch\test.mxd")
            pdoc = pApp.Document
            Dim obj2 As Object
            obj2 = pdoc.VBProject
            For Each vbComp In obj2.vbcomponents
                ''' not sure how to check?
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            pApp.Shutdown()
        End Try
    End Sub
```